# Flatten points into SVG polyline Polymer

Tags: svg, polymer

I have the following data structure:

```
'points': [
  {
    'x': 5535,
    'y': 5535
  },
  {
    'x': 5535,
    'y': 60000
  },
  {
    'x': 60000,
    'y': 60000
  },
  {
    'x': 60000,
    'y': 5535
  }
];
```

I would like to flatten it to `5535,5535 5535,60000 60000,60000 60000,5535` to use as a `polyline` `points` attribute.

I have the following in Polymer `<template>`

```
<polyline
    id="polygon",
    points="{{points | polygonPoints | toSvgPoints(width, height)}}"
    stroke="rgba({{colour.r}}, {{colour.g}}, {{colour.b}}, {{opacity}})"
    fill="rgba({{colour.r}}, {{colour.g}}, {{colour.b}}, {{opacity * 0.6}})"
    stroke-width="{{lineWidth}}"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round"
/>
```

Where `polygonPoints` and `toSvgPoints` filters look like so:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the polygon points for this object.
 * @param point optionally provide a list of normalized points
 * @returns the polygon points or all points if a line
 */
polygonPoints: function(points) {
  var array = points.slice(0);
  points = points || this.points;
  array.push(points[0])
  return array;
},

/**
 * Retrieves the polygon points for this object.
 * @param point optionally provide a list of normalized points
 * @returns the polygon points or all points if a line
 */
toSvgPoints: function(points, width, height) {
  var i, string = '';
  points = points || this.points;
  for (i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
    string += this.normalizedToActual(points[i].x, width);
    string += ',';
    string += this.normalizedToActual(points[i].y, height);
    string += ' ';
  }
  return string;
},
```

This works, the `toSvgPoints` returns the correct points but the bindings to the point values do not get set up automagically by Polymer. For example, if I modify `this.points[0].x = 4219` the polygon doesn't update because the binding hasn't been created to the polygon attribute.

Is this something that just can't be solved without providing some other method that invokes a redraw?  Ideally I'd just want to do this:

```
<polyline
    id="polygon",
    points="{{x,y for (points | polygonPoints)}}"
    ...
/>
```

Which would stamp out the `x` and `y` values in the `points` attribute and set up the bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PolymerExpressions only observes objects that are directly referenced in an expression, so in this case it observes `points`, but not the properties on the elements in the array. If you replace a point, the expression will update, but it won't if you modify a point.

There are a few ways to deal with this. If you know where a point is being modified, at you have a reference to the list there, you can manually notify on the list. I usually work with Polymer.Dart, but I think that the `notify()` function in observe-js is what you're looking for: https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js/blob/master/src/observe.js#L1076

Alternatively, instead of returning a static projection of the points, have `toSvgPoints` listen to all of its dependencies: `points`, `x` and `y` for each point, `width` and `height`. When an input changes, update the output array. This will cause a chain of updates that propagates to your view.

Use Polymer's observe-js library to do observation. It polyfills `Object.observe()` on platforms that don't have it. https://github.com/Polymer/observe-js#objectobserver

Comment: How do i make `toSvgPoints` listen to the elements? `onMutation` is for light DOM elements and that didnt work.

Comment: I added a link to observe-js

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure but I guess Polymer doesn't observe individual attributes inside an array. You could try to replace the item at that position:

`this.points[0] = {x:4219,y:this.points[0].y}`

or alternatively create a new array and set it to this.points ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to observe the attributes when put through a filter.

Comment: This is correct. PolymerExpressions only observes the references that directly appear in an expression, not in the properties that hang off of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well that took ages. Don't use a `polyline` use a `path`:

```
<path
    id="zone"
    on-down="{{dragStart}}"
    on-up="{{dragEnd}}"
    d="M {{points[0].x| max(width)}} {{points[0].y | max(height)}} {{points | polygonPoints | toSvgPoints(width, height)}}"
    fill="rgba({{colour.r}}, {{colour.g}}, {{colour.b}}, {{(selected ? 0.8 : 0.6) * 0.6}})"
    stroke="rgba({{colour.r}}, {{colour.g}}, {{colour.b}}, {{(selected ? 0.8 : 0.6)}})"
    stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round"
/>
```

The `M {{points[0].x| max(width)}} {{points[0].y | max(height)}}` at the start of the `d` attribute forces the redraw.

Comment: I think you'll find that the only reason this works now is because you're directly referencing `points[0].x` in an expression, not because you're using `<path>`. If you modify `points[1].x` it won't update.

Comment: Its seems to work fine...any point i move it just works. I thought the same as you.

Comment: I'm not sure. I put that in and it all started working. I needed to jump out from work but will do some testing next week.

Comment: I have no idea what magic polymer is pulling. The d attribute is `M0 0  L0 0 L0 0` but all the points correctly update.