# Polymer, SVG path, Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, polymer

Inside an `svg` element (which is inside my Polymer element) I have the following code:

```
<path
id="zone"
on-track="{{trackAction}}"
touch-action="none"
t="M {{points[0].x| max(correctWidth)}} {{points[0].y | max(correctHeight)}}  {{points | toSvgPoints2(correctWidth, correctHeight)}} {{points | polygonPoint(correctWidth, correctHeight)}}"
d="M {{points[0].x| max(correctWidth)}} {{points[0].y | max(correctHeight)}}  {{points | toSvgPoints2(correctWidth, correctHeight)}} {{points | polygonPoint(correctWidth, correctHeight)}}"
fill="url(#crossHatch{{index}})"/>
```

which results in the following in IE (note the empty `d` attribute):

```
<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
id="zone" 
fill="url(#crossHatch260320416)" 
d="" 
touch-action="none" 
on-track="{{ trackAction }}" 
t="M 345 277  L345 277 L649 277 L649 442 L345 442  L345 277 " />
```

The `d` attribute is populated correctly in Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, just not in IE.

This is a continuation of the following topic:
[Flatten points into SVG polyline Polymer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829253/flatted-points-into-svg-polyline-polymer)

I know it's a pretty new area and IE is not a first choice testing browser for the Polymer guys, but if anyone has come across this weird behavior and found a solution (or at least a good kludge) that would be perfect!

Comment: I don't have IE, but does this jsbin replicate the bug? http://jsbin.com/gusajika/2/edit?html,output

Comment: That's correct, using the attached jsbin example we can see it draws a rectangle correctly in all browsers apart from IE, once we modify "d" into "_d" it draws a rectangle correctly even in IE. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE deletes the invalid `d` attribute value before Polymer has a chance to read it and parse out the data bindings. As a workaround, you can prepend an attribute with an underscore and Polymer will create the real attribute with valid data after loading.

```
<path _d="M {{points[0].x| max(correctWidth)}} {{points[0].y | max(correctHeight)}}  {{points | toSvgPoints2(correctWidth, correctHeight)}} {{points | polygonPoint(correctWidth, correctHeight)}}"/>
```

becomes

```
<path d="M 345 277  L345 277 L649 277 L649 442 L345 442  L345 277" _d="M {{points[0].x| max(correctWidth)}} {{points[0].y | max(correctHeight)}}  {{points | toSvgPoints2(correctWidth, correctHeight)}} {{points | polygonPoint(correctWidth, correctHeight)}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a correct solution! You've made my day :)

Comment: Also I think this is a more generic solution, just came across another attribute "value" and preceding it with an underscore fixed again.